# How to add some space in vertical between two paragraphs/sentences in beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

In one slide, I find that two paragraphs are too close vertically. Then I want extra space. However, I find that applying more \ \ does not work in beamer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a trivial question: see [this TeX.SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/add-space-between-paragraphs-in-beamer) and [this other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/how-do-i-set-the-space-between-paragraphs-with-beamer).

The way to set the *default* `parskip` may be the following:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\parskip=20pt

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise, if you want to change the `parskip` only *locally* (as I seem to understand), you can use the above syntax inside your `frame`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\parskip=20pt

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\parskip=20pt

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\parskip=0pt

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The second `\parskip=0pt` sets all the following occurrencies of this length back to 0 pt (as I think 0 is the default here otherwise).

Answer (score 5):

Try inserting vertical space using `\vspace`, e.g. `\vspace{1cm}`.

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3543233/mattallegro really helps. If one doesn't have much idea about the layout or format of the document they are writing in, like me(an already existing layout), they can use this in between their paragraphs to alter the para spacings.

> \parskip=2pt

During my analysis, I encountered that `\vspace` is sometimes throwing bad results but using parskip was helpful.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to give space between two paragraphs,
use \newline as many times as the space you want. Using \newline once serves the same purpose as the double-backslash.